# How to install ROS melodic over Network proxy

Tags: ros

Maybe it is a repeated question, but really i have no solution

i am trying to install ROS melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, using my Wifi the things went good, but at my office where i have a desktop with restricted policy to use a proxy i have some problem

1. the ubuntu software & update can't install the updates even i have connected to internet and the proxy setting  was setupped in system setting
2. when i tried`sudo http_proxy=myproxy:myport apt-get update` the update process failed with this message `some index failed to download, they have been ignored or old ones used instead`
3. i try to install ROS even though the ubuntu updates were failed but again the terminal shows `Reading Package list...Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information...Done
   Enable to locate package ros-melodic-desktop-full`

i tried multiple solutions via google but all were failed.

Why isn't enough to setup the proxy from system setting one time ?

If i have windows10 which accessing the net using the same proxy, Can i get the update by connecting ubuntu to windows hotspot ?

If i take the hard disk where the ubuntu installed and try to get update using another computer, Can i get them correctly?

Comment: Do you need to provide a username/password? Did you ask the network administrator at your office?

Comment: the command "sudo http_proxy=myproxy:myport apt-get update" work fine, it was a conflict in my IP

Comment: If this solved your problem then you should answer your own question. This way the question is marked as answered and leaves the unanswered questions. You can also remove the question if you think that it was not a real problem because of the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Aswered in the comment from [@Mjd Kassam comment above](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19535/how-to-install-ros-melodic-over-network-proxy#comment32167_19535)

> the command "sudo http_proxy=myproxy:myport apt-get update" work fine,
> it was a conflict in my IP